# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, lambda, cors

happy new year everybody!

So I have a reactJS API call which looks like this:

```
 async function callApi() {

    const requestData = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: token
      }
    }

    if (calledAPI === false) {
      let data = await API
      .get('caresyncauthapi' , '/access', requestData)
      .then(response => {
        let arr = {};
        arr = response.Items;
        setZorgSearchData(arr)
      })
    }
    calledAPI = true;
  }
```

The Lambda it calls looks like this:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    if (event.requestContext.authorizer) {
        const claims = event.requestContext.authorizer.claims;
        username = claims['cognito:username'];
      
    }

    var params = {
        TableName: tableName, 
        IndexName: "ZorgverlenerID-index",
        KeyConditionExpression: "#ZorgverlenerID = :zorg_id",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
          "#ZorgverlenerID": "ZorgverlenerID"
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: { 
          ":zorg_id": username
        }
    };


  
    try {
        data = await dynamodb.query(params).promise();
        console.log( "Status code : 200"); 
        console.log(data.Items);

        let response = 
        {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {
                 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
             }, 
            body: JSON.stringify(data.Items)
        }
        return JSON.stringify(response);

    } catch (error){
        console.log( "Status code : 400, Error code : ", error.stack);
    }

     
    


};
```

Basically the Lambda gets the context from the sent token (username of the person logged in).
It then queries this database with this username, it then puts the result in a json and returns it.
The await dynamodb.query(params).promise(); gives me an 200 (success) and it also prints the correct data I want to return in cloudwatch.
But when the data returns to my ReactJS application i recieve:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://qcesrr2td3.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/devl/access' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
xhr.js:187 GET https://qcesrr2td3.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/devl/access net::ERR_FAILED 502
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:187
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:13
```

Thing I already tried:

- Enabling CORS in the API gateway
- Changing up the headers in the response
- Returning the response without JSON.stringify, its null then

Does anybody have an idea what I can still change?

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it by not stringifying my response:

```
try {
        data = await dynamodb.query(params).promise();
        console.log( "Status code : 200"); 
        console.log(data.Items);

        let response = 
        {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "OPTIONS,POST,GET,PUT"
             }, 
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        }

        return response;

    } catch (error){
        console.log( "Status code : 400, Error code : ", error.stack);
    }
```

Weird because this code worked for a week then suddenly stopped. Oh well it works again.